# Tensorflow Datasets GPU memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management, conv-neural-network, gpu

I'm training a CNN using TensorFlow 2.10 with a Windows PC and a Navidia GPU.

Using task manager the GPU never gets over 10% often as low as 2/3%. But the memory in use slowly climbs. **Does this suggest the GPU is not working? With larger training sets it slows down training towards the end of the first epoch and then seems to freeze during validation testing.**

As far as I can tell the GPU is working and the code should be reading from disk one batch at a time.
This is the GPU information I get:

```
2022-12-01 13:58:25.441213: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5472 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6


2022-12-01 13:58:28.187036: I tensorflow_io/core/kernels/cpu_check.cc:128] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow IO binary was not compiled to use: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
```

I have ~1.4million training tiles shape of each (32,32,4). Using a smaller subset of 144,000 of these does work for a 20 epoch model. The following code loads this training set to put these into the model:

```
 #get a file path that will find all the water and all the land images
data_dir = folder + '/*/*'

# create dataset using find file, shuffle
ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(data_dir, shuffle=True)

# Read the images and labels, add batchsize and number of epochs
ds = ds.shuffle(len(ds)).map(process_image).batch(bs) #.repeat(epoch)

# set validation size
training_size = int(len(ds)*0.66)

# splits datset into test and validation
Xy_train = ds.take(training_size)
Xy_test = ds.skip(training_size)



....
CNN.fit(Xy_train, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(Xy_test))
```

Comment: You should run the [TensorFlow profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras), this will help you to see where your bottleneck might be. Given the small size of your images, you might simply have a too small batch size to take full advantage of the GPU, so you might want to increase it.

Comment: Struggling to get profiler to work but increasing the batch size doesn't stop the increasing memory usage and low GPU %